# benchtest in Matlab

Tags: testing, matlab, performance, benchmarking

Does anyone know of a good test in Matlab to compare machine specs?  Is is going to be very code specific?

I'm guessing that I could try some large matrix operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The builtin [`bench`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bench.html) function tests a whole bunch of different things, and shows comparisons for some known machines.